# foreign key no parent error

Tags: java, hibernate

This is really why I quit using Hibernate to manage my relationships for me. Too many new gray hairs.

Hibernate 3.6.10

OK, I have two classes, Schedule and Event. Schedule has many events, but an event has only one schedule.

Schedule:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.schedule;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.helper.DateHelper;
import com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.Pojo;

/**
 * A particular collection of events that can be shared
 * @author Thom
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCHEDULE")
@NamedQueries( {
    @NamedQuery(name = Schedule.COUNT_SCHED_ID,      query =  "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
                                                              "FROM Schedule s " +
                                                              "WHERE s.scheduleId = :scheduleId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Schedule.COUNT_SCHED_NAME,    query =  "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
                                                              "FROM   ScheduleRole r, Schedule s, SystemUser u " +
                                                              "WHERE  u.email = :email " +
                                                               " AND u.id = r.systemUserId " +
                                                               " AND r.scheduleId = s.id " +
                                                               " AND s.name = :scheduleName "),
    @NamedQuery(name = Schedule.QUERY_EVENTS_BY_USER, query =  "SELECT  r.roleType, s " +
                                                               "FROM    Schedule s, ScheduleRole r, SystemUser u " +
                                                               "WHERE   u.email = :email " +
                                                               "  AND   u.id = r.systemUserId " +
                                                               "  AND   r.scheduleId = s.id " +
                                                               " ")
    }
)
public class Schedule extends Pojo {

    public static final int        LENGTH_SCHEDULE_ID        = 32;
    public static final String     COUNT_SCHED_ID            = "countScheduleId";
    public static final String     COUNT_SCHED_NAME          = "countScheduleName";
    public static final String     QUERY_EVENTS_BY_USER      = "findEventsByUser";

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable=false)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer     id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable=false)
    private String      name;

    @Column(name = "SCHEDULE_ID", nullable=false, unique=true, length=LENGTH_SCHEDULE_ID)
    private String      scheduleId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    private Collection<Event>   events;

    /**
     * Copy all members from one to the other
     * @param from the from
     * @param to the to
     * @param copySubMembers if true, copy sub members like entity
     */
    public static void copy(Schedule from, Schedule to, boolean copySubMembers){
        to.setId(from.getId());
        to.setName(from.getName());
        to.setScheduleId(from.getScheduleId());
        if(copySubMembers){
            to.setEvents(from.getEvents());
        }
    }

    /**
     * no-arg constructor
     */
    public Schedule() {
    }

    /**
     * copy constructor
     */
    public Schedule(Schedule schedule) {
        copy(schedule, this, true);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.Pojo#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(super.toString());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getName());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getScheduleId());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getEvents());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((scheduleId == null) ? 0 : scheduleId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Schedule other = (Schedule) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (scheduleId == null) {
            if (other.scheduleId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!scheduleId.equals(other.scheduleId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public final Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public final void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public String getScheduleId() {
        return scheduleId == null?scheduleId = DateHelper.getUniqueID():scheduleId;
    }

    /**
     * @param scheduleId
     */
    public void setScheduleId(String scheduleId) {
        this.scheduleId = scheduleId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the events
     */
    public Collection<Event> getEvents() {
        return events==null?events = new ArrayList<>():events;
    }

    /**
     * @param events the events to set
     */
    public void setEvents(Collection<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }
}
```

Event:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.schedule;

import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.Pojo;

/**
 * A particular event entry in a calendar
 * @author Thom
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
@NamedQueries( {
    }
)
public class Event extends Pojo {

    /**
     * Length of the randomly generated event ID
     */
    private static final int            LENGTH_EVENT_ID             = 32;

    @Column(name = "ID", nullable=false)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer     id;

    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar    start;

    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar    end;

    @Column(name = "EVENT_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String      eventName;

    @Column(name = "EVENT_ID", nullable=false, unique=true, length=LENGTH_EVENT_ID)
    private String      eventId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHEDULE_ID")
    private Schedule    schedule;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String      location;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((end == null) ? 0 : end.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((eventName == null) ? 0 : eventName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((location == null) ? 0 : location.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((schedule == null) ? 0 : schedule.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((start == null) ? 0 : start.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Event other = (Event) obj;
        if (end == null) {
            if (other.end != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!end.equals(other.end))
            return false;
        if (eventName == null) {
            if (other.eventName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!eventName.equals(other.eventName))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (location == null) {
            if (other.location != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!location.equals(other.location))
            return false;
        if (schedule == null) {
            if (other.schedule != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!schedule.equals(other.schedule))
            return false;
        if (start == null) {
            if (other.start != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!start.equals(other.start))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.Pojo#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(super.toString());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getEventName());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getTimestamp(getStart()));
        sb.append('-');
        sb.append(getTimestamp(getEnd()));
        sb.append("|scheduleId=");
        Schedule schedule = getSchedule();
        sb.append(schedule==null?"null":schedule.getId());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getLocation());
        sb.append('|');
        sb.append(getEventId());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public final Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public final void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * The start date of the event in UTC
     * @return the start
     */
    public final Calendar getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    /**
     * The start date of the event in UTC
     * @param start the start to set
     */
    public final void setStart(Calendar start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    /**
     * The end date of the event in UTC
     * @return the end
     */
    public final Calendar getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    /**
     * The end date of the event in UTC
     * @param end the end to set
     */
    public final void setEnd(Calendar end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventId
     */
    public String getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventId the eventId to set
     */
    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventName
     */
    public final String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventName the eventName to set
     */
    public final void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the location
     */
    public final String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    /**
     * @param location the location to set
     */
    public final void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    /**
     * @return the schedule
     */
    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    /**
     * @param schedule the schedule to set
     */
    public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Now at the point I'm getting the exception, I have created a schedule and then added 4 events to the schedule and am calling update on my schedule DAO to save the events. Here is my current code:

```
public Schedule update(Schedule schedule) {
    //first save the events
    for(Event event:schedule.getEvents()){
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(event); //<-Fails here
    }
    Schedule schedule2 = getHibernateTemplate().get(Schedule.class, schedule.getId());
    Schedule.copy(schedule, schedule2, false);
    System.err.println(schedule2.toString());
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(schedule2);
    return retrieveById(schedule2.getId());
}
```

All fields on my event are populated except the ID, which is auto generated. Here's the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.schedule.Event]; SQL [insert into EVENT (ID, END_TIME, EVENT_ID, EVENT_NAME, LOCATION, SCHEDULE_ID, START_TIME) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [FK3F47A7AA91E64F]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.schedule.Event]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
    at com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.dao.hibernate.schedule.ScheduleHibernateDAO.update(ScheduleHibernateDAO.java:71)
    at com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.dao.hibernate.schedule.ScheduleHibernateDAO.update(ScheduleHibernateDAO.java:1)
    at com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.service.calendar.impl.CalendarServiceImpl.update(CalendarServiceImpl.java:168)
    at com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.service.calendar.impl.CalendarServiceImplTest.testGetCalendars(CalendarServiceImplTest.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.heavyweightsoftware.leal.model.schedule.Event]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK3F47A7AA91E64F table: EVENT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Util.java:215)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(JDBCPreparedStatement.java:4617)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCPreparedStatement.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:56)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK3F47A7AA91E64F table: EVENT
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:131)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Constraint.java:898)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.checkInsert(Constraint.java:816)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.performIntegrityChecks(StatementDML.java:1318)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(StatementDML.java:795)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(StatementInsert.java:139)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(StatementDMQL.java:190)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1294)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Session.java:956)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(JDBCPreparedStatement.java:4609)
    ... 49 more
```

Thanks!
Heartbroken in Lexington:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to perform a join from your `Schedule` entity to your `Event` entity, when there is no foreign key relationship in that direction.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
private Collection<Event>   events;
```

With the above code you are instructing your JPA provider to retrieve all events for which the Schedule's `id` column matches with the primary key from `Event`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you intended. You should allow `Event` to define the mapping and then reference that from `Schedule`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "schedule")
private Collection<Event>   events;
```

Also, I would recommend using `Sets` to store your collections, since Hibernate has a known problem when storing multiple associations (bags) in an entity, unless you do.